# When did the Uncharted series add aerial takedowns/attacks?

Tags: uncharted-series

There doesn't seem to be any option to attack an enemy from an elevated position in 'Drake's Fortune' and 'Among Thieves'. The same applies to the PS Vita entry 'Golden Abyss', released after 'Uncharted 3: Drake's Deception' ([the animation system was reportedly pared down](https://www.eurogamer.net/articles/digitalfoundry-tech-analysis-uncharted-golden-abyss)).

I'm in the process of playing through The Nathan Drake and Legacy of Thieves collections — did Drake's Deception add aerial attacks or were they only introduced in 'A Thief's End' for PS4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aerial takedowns were definitely not introduced in Uncharted 4, they were already present in Uncharted 3.

Here's a video compilation of stealth takedowns in Uncharted 3, and the first one shown is an aerial:

This attack was likely introduced in Uncharted 3, from [Uncharted wiki](https://uncharted.fandom.com/wiki/Melee#Stealth):

> Drake's Deception features additional stealth moves, such as a "jumping takedown". This attack consists of the Drake jumping from a higher platform onto an enemy below, thereby snapping the enemy's neck or knocking them out.

Comment: I assume that you're familiar with Uncharted 1 and 2, I haven't yet completed the sequel (or played any multiplayer, which isn't available for the PS4 ports).

Comment: Does Uncharted 4 have "aerial attacks", meaning moves which don't necessarily immediately kill the opponent? I recall seeing some — a "jump-punch" — in a video (I haven't watched any footage since to avoid spoilers).

Comment: @user598527 iirc, aerial attacks were only one-shot moves. I don't remember anything not lethal from above.